# Integrate Disqus comments with Android

Tags: php, android, disqus

I am trying to integrate Disqus comments to my Android application, and I am following this tutorial:

> http://globeotter.com/blog/disqus-android-code/

I didn't understand well part about disqus_identifier. As you can see from the code below I use this code to acces showcomments.php on my server.

> webDisqus.loadUrl("http://balkanandroid.com/showcomments.php?disqus_id="+identifer);

Where identifer is part of url behind top level domain name, something like this:

> http://balkanandroid.com/graficka-evolucija-nexus-telefona/
>   And I use /graficka-evolucija-nexus-telefona/ as disqus identifer.

And I get this error message:

> We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide.

Here is server side php code>

Comment: This error almost always has to do with an incorrect configuration. Can you share your PHP server code as well? I'm guessing the problem is there.

Comment: This is PHP server side code: http://pastebin.com/m4ZJHcQj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example code provided, this is a pretty easy fix. Just change this line:

`var disqus_shortname = '<balkanandroid>';`

to this:

`var disqus_shortname = 'balkanandroid';`

Comment: Cool, this works! Anyway is there chance to get number of comments for some topics? Because I want in my Android application to show user how many comments is there for that topic?

Comment: What would you consider a topic? Is that a group of comment threads? You can check out using this: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131783

Comment: Hi, it seems that I have a problem. :) When i run my PHP script on this link: http://balkanandroid.com/showcomments.php?disqus_id=/koji-je-trenutno-najbolji-mobilni-telefon/, it says that there are no comments. But here is the real link on my website: http://balkanandroid.com/koji-je-trenutno-najbolji-mobilni-telefon/ and as you can see, there are 3 comments. What's wrong?

Comment: The Disqus identifier on your main page is '9944 http://balkanandroid.com/?p=9944' -- so it needs to be that on your mobile page to work properly.

Comment: p=9944 is just shortlink for this page (article) on my site. I have many articles like that. And I am asking how I can know which is  Disqus identifier, when I send request from mobile app to PHP server script with this http://balkanandroid.com/showcomments.php?disqus_id=identifier

Comment: In short, what I need send from my app to PHP server side script to get Disqus cooments for every news article (post) on my site?

Comment: The identifier is based off of your Wordpress post ID. So something like this: `{post_id} {yourdomain}/?p={post_id}`

Comment: Okey, that leads me to this url: http://balkanandroid.com/?p=9944, but that opens full page of my website, I need just disqus coomments, other part of that page like contet and so on, I have already in my via RSS.